# mysql join two rows with shared column entry

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have one table which stores tags for files. The tags can be of different types. There are many files, each with tags stored for them of different types.

columns: file, tagtype, tags

So let's say I have two rows for one file:

```
cyclist.jpg | date | 04-05-2012
cyclist.jpg | face | true
```

I would like to select into one row, all tags for a file, such that I have a mysql result:

cyclist.jpg 04-05-2012 true

At present I carry out two queries for the above, one for each tagtype. I want to know if I can do some kind of join, with the same table, on the same columns (tags), just based on one shared column (file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join automatically two rows that means that probably you can just create one row without spliting it:

```
file         | date       | face 
cyclist.jpg  | 04-05-2012 | true
```

Otherwise if you need to keep separate rows, just select all rows in one query:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from tags where file='cyclist.jpg'");
```

and then iterate them to fulfil 'merged' record:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from tags_table where file='cyclist.jpg'");

$mergedRow = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    foreach ($row as $rowKey => $rowValue) {
        if (!array_key_exists($rowKey, $mergedRow)) {
            $mergedRow[$rowKey] = $rowValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

As promised here's a sample of joining two rows into one with single query, however I would still recommend `$mergedRow` approach in PHP to merging them :)

```
CREATE TABLE `files_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_type` enum('PARENT','CHILD') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PARENT',
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `face` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then you can 'pair' PARENT-CHILDREN sets with:

```
SELECT t1.file, t1.date, t2.face
    FROM files_table AS t1 JOIN files_table AS t2 ON (t1.file = t2.file)
    WHERE t1.tag_type = 'PARENT' AND t2.tag_type = 'CHILD'
    GROUP BY file
```

Comment: Thanks biesior. At present I do it in code, but would like to select them all as one mysql result row.
How can I create one result one with file | date | face as you first write?

Comment: @Sam: I showed you as it should be **stored** in DB, joining records from the same tables is not good idea, because you have almost no control on how values from conflicting columns will be merged, anyway I will write you a sample query soon.

Comment: The DB is structured as it is due to the semi-structured format of data. Some files have date information, some have face information, there are also about twenty other optional fields, which would be inefficient to have as columns in each row, as most files only have one or two tag types.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort Biesior. That was exactly what I was looking for. Knew it must have been possible, just didn't know the RDB terminology to search for it.